# PHP webpage doesn't launch unix command even after updated sudoers

Tags: php, exec, sudo

Basically I am trying to restart a service from a php web page.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
exec ('/usr/bin/sudo /etc/init.d/portmap restart');
?>
```

But, in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`, I get

> unable to change to sudoers gid: Operation not permitted

and in /var/log/messages, I get

> Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.536:777): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=4851 comm="sh" name="var" dev=dm-0 ino=114241 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t tclass=dir
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.549:778): avc:  denied  { setrlimit } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tclass=process
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.565:779): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" name="shadow" dev=dm-0 ino=379669 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=system_u:object_r:shadow_t tclass=file
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.568:780): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" name="shadow" dev=dm-0 ino=379669 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=system_u:object_r:shadow_t tclass=file
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.571:781): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" capability=6 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tclass=capability
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.574:782): avc:  denied  { setuid } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" capability=7 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tclass=capability
>   Sep 22 15:01:56 ri kernel: audit(1222063316.577:783): avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=4851 comm="sudo" capability=6 scontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tcontext=root:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t tclass=capability

In my visudo, I added those lines

> User_Alias      WWW=apache
>
> WWW ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL

Can you please help me ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your help,

tiBoun

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not with sudo at the moment, but with [SELinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selinux), which is (reasonably) set to deny the HTTPD from gaining root privileges.
You will need to either explicitly allow this (you can use [audit2allow](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/SELinux/audit2allow) for this), or set SELinux to be permissive instead. I'd suggest the former.

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working now !
Just had to disable SELinux in /etc/selinux/config and change to SELINUX=disabled.

Cheers,

tiBoun

Answer (score 5):

The error you are getting seems to be related to your SELinux configuration.  You might try temporarily disabling that.

As an aside, I would strongly suggest that you adjust your sudo configuration to be more restrictive.

```
User_Alias WWW=apache
Cmnd_Alias WEBCMDS=/etc/init.d/portmap
WWW ALL=NOPASSWD: WEBCMDS
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise, I am currently just testing, of course for security reason, I will slim down the available commands.

Cheers ;D

tiBoun

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the problem recently and the accepted answer above helped. However, I would like to post this answer to elaborate the same, so that the next person does not need to spend time much, like me!

Follow section 7 of the following link: https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux.

Do grep with `httpd_sys_script_t`.

Basically the steps are:

```
# grep httpd_sys_script_t /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M httpdallowsudo
# semodule -i httpdallowsudo.pp
```

Answer (score -3):

This is probably down to something like trying to execute sudo in a non-interactive shell.

If you do a grep for 'sudo' in your apache users mail log you might find things like this

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo