# How to connect as linux root user in php

Tags: php, linux, root, shell-exec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to run PHP exec() as root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598231/how-to-run-php-exec-as-root)

Hey Guys,

I need to connect the linux root user in php.

i hosted my file in var/www/html/connect.php

I need to execute one shell_exec script. It says it "Only root user can login".

How can i change that? or Please help me to sort the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598231/how-to-run-php-exec-as-root http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173201/sudo-in-php-exe

Answer (score 0):

Usually php/apache executes the php files using the **www-data** user. if you need to execute your shell, all you need to do is to give the corresponding permissions to www-data for that file using **chmod**

Answer (score -1):

you need to give apache (or whatever is running php) `sudo` rights to the server, than you can run as root, bu doing:

```
sudo command
```

Comment: is this safe at all??? giving sudo rights to www-data seems too dangerous

Comment: what? your giving it to `apache`, see the dupe

Comment: Bad advice without narrowing it down to only allowing `sudo` for that script he is running. If there was an exploit on the server and someone was able to inject code, it could lead to massive problems. IE: `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD:/path/to/script` But there again, depending on what the script does can lead to holes. So yea, the OP really needs to look at the cause and effect and consequences of such actions before implementing.