# Running Bash Script from PHP which creates VMs

Tags: php, bash, web, virtual-machine, virtualization

Currently I am working on a project which require to create a vm from a click on the webpage.

This is my bash script which i am using to create a vm and it is working perfect but when called through php i am unable to run this script.

```
 #!/bin/bash
 set -e
 if [ ! -f "/tmp/value.dat" ] ; then
      value=0
 else
      value=`cat /tmp/value.dat`
 fi
 value=`expr ${value} + 1`
 echo "${value}" > /tmp/value.dat
 qemu-img create -f raw /var/lib/libvirt/images/disk$value.img 5.1G
 virt-install --name=instance$value --ram=1024 --arch=i686 --vcpus=1 --os-type=linux  --disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/disk$value.img,bus=virtio,format=raw --location ftp://10.21.40.227/ --extra-args "ks=ftp://10.21.40.227/ks.cfg"  --autostart
```

This is the php script that i am trying to run

```
 <?php
    $bashfile = shell_exec("sudo /root/Desktop/install.sh");
    echo "<pre>$bashfile<pre>";
 ?>
```

This is the entry in the sudoers file by me

**apache ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL**

Still i am unable to run the bash script via php suggest some solutions.

Comment: can you post the bash script that you are using?

Comment: Post the *localized* technical problem. Not that you can't do it. Post the command(s) and the stderr/stdout and then someone'd be able to help you. the c club?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598231/how-to-run-php-exec-as-root) and particularly [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5753115/2463134). Right now, you're executing '/root/Desktop/install.sh' on the same host which is running PHP/apache. Don't you want to do it *on a remote host*?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that `$PATH` is not set correctly when it is not called from a shell. Try using absolute paths for `qemu-img` and `virt-install`.

Another problem I see here: you really don't want Apache to be able to run **any** command through `sudo`, do you? Change your sudoers line to this to limit it to your script only:

```
apache  ALL=NOPASSWD:/root/Desktop/install.sh
```