# run commands with root privileges in php with url

Tags: php, sudo, sudoers

I have simple PHP code like this:

```
<?php
print_r(shell_exec($_GET['c']));
```

now I want to run commands with root privileges through URL.
I have added `www-data` as sudoers and I try this
`curl -vv "http://localhost/index.php?c=echo mypass|sudo -S -s 'whoami'"` but I can't see anything in output

**This code is just for fun, also I don't want to write my commands in bash script and run them with PHP, I want to know whats wrong with this code**

Comment: I know,it's just for fun, I don't want to use it anywhere

Comment: that's a really bad idea to run a command with root privileges from an URL. You really should avoid that.

maybe this thread will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598231/how-to-run-php-exec-as-root

Comment: Guys he stated it's "just for fun". Let him do what he wants, as long as he knows why it's a bad idea :) *Have you also tried executing your script with sudo*?

Comment: suppose I can't run this script with sudo command, all I can do  it's just run this file regulary and  I can add `www-data` to sudoers user groups too @Jimbo

Comment: @EbrahimPoursadeqi: So when someone makes the effort to answer a question of yours, you delete it?!