# Creating a PHP web page that enables you to reboot the server in Linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I want to create a web page that allows the user to initiate a reboot on the linux server. Obviously this would only be avaliable for system admins and would also be controlled by using iptables.

Below is a sample of code that I was thinking of using but I wanted to know if there is another way to do this and how also to use this in a web page? Also is there any thing else  that I should consider?

```
$command = "cat $pass | su -c 'shutdown -r now'";
$output = array();
try{
    echo shell_exec($command);
    exec($command, $output);
    system($command, $output);
}
catch(Exception $e) {
    print "Unable to shutdown system...\n";
}

foreach ($output as $line) {
    print "$line<br>";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chances are, the user PHP is running under won't have permission to reboot the server.  The best thing to do is specifically allow PHP permission to do so via /etc/sudoers.  This question, along with one or two others here on SO helped me make something similar work for my application: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113728/php-webpage-doesnt-launch-unix-command-even-after-updated-sudoers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have checked this one http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/shutdown-and-reboot-linux-system-via-php-script-713379/ ?

Comment: So basically have a script that is in a folder within the website and then execute that script from the php web page. Do I need to add anything to the above to allow me to do this with respect to specifying that this is a script and not a web page? Also is there anything I need to add from a permissions perspective? Thanks

Comment: Sorry just answered my own question and rebooted my linux pc. :) thanks