# How can I run a bin file using php?

Tags: php, html

Here is the problem: I have 5 bin files generated by c++ code, I'm developing a GUI for execute that files using php pages.
I try to execute the bin file with the php function exec.
When I load the page nothing appends, I want that the bin starts running local showing me the results in the shell window. calibrate is the name of the bin file.Is it possible?

```
 <html>
  <body>
  <?php 
   exec('calibrate');
  ?><br>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**UPDATE**

I checked the PHP error log and I have a permission denied error, the problem is that I modified all the permissions with 777 (for the moment) also in the parent directory but I receive the same error.
I don't know if can be useful but if I call the command whoamII read apacheI. Hoping someone can help.

Comment: Try giving `exec()` the full path of the script.

Comment: Try enabling error reporting during development so you see what goes wrong on the page. Or look in the php error log. (Sometimes found in the webserver log)

Comment: You want to run php script from shell that will exec bin file and output results?  Why would you include php tags withing html tags though?

Answer (score 0):

1. Type full path of bin file in the exec function

   ```
   exec("C:\xampp\apache\bin\ax.exe");
   ```

   2.Also confirm exec function is not listed in the disabled functions list in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

From the [official documentation for `exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), **it returns the last line from the result of the command**:

> #### Return Values
>
> The last line from the result of the command. If you need to execute a
>   command and have all the data from the command passed directly back
>   without any interference, use the `passthru()` function.
>
> To get the output of the executed command, be sure to set and use the
>   output parameter.

If you have only one line of output, then simple echo it:

```
<?php echo exec('/path/to/calibrate') ?>
```

Otherwise, pass in the second argument to get the array of output:

```
<?php
   $output = array();
   exec('/path/to/calibrate', $output);

   // Print it however you need
   print_r($output);
?>
```

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be
>   filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing
>   whitespace, such as `\n`, is not included in this array. Note that if
>   the array already contains some elements, `exec()` will append to the
>   end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements,
>   call `unset()` on the array before passing it to `exec()`.

Comment: I think that the path is right, but I don't want print the output in the webpage, I want only have the same results that I have if I write calibrate in the shell. It starts the calibration of my hardware and show 3 pages of results

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me after searching for hours! Good Luck! :)

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t '/whatever/scripts(/.*)?' 
restorecon -R -v /whatever/scripts/
```

[Tell SELinux to Give Apache Execute Access to PHP Files Outside Document Root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395845/tell-selinux-to-give-apache-execute-access-to-php-files-outside-document-root)