# Laravel Permission Denied

Tags: php, apache, laravel, laravel-5

Tonight, I tried to run `composer install` and all the dependencies installed correctly, and then composer ran `php artisan clear compiled` and I ran into trouble.

Here's the error it returned:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled

                                                                                                                          
  [ErrorException]                                                                                                        
  file_put_contents(/srv/something/site/bootstrap/cache/services.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  
                                                                                                                          

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


                      
  [RuntimeException]  
  Error Output:       
                      


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Naturally, I googled it and found everyone on the [laracast forums](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/cant-composer-update-1) saying to make the directory I was missing, so I did and the command ran again fine.  When I went to any page I got this: `file_put_contents(/differentNameDependingOnPageButAlwaysRandomLettersAndNumbers.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

For example here's the traceback for the login page:

```
ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
in Filesystem.php line 81
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'file_put_contents(/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied', '/srv/something/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php', '81', array('path' => '/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php', 'contents' => '<?php $__env->startSection('title'); ?> Admin Login <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('form'); ?> <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action = "login"> <?php echo e($error); ?><?php /*TODO this doesn't show up now, when you do login make it show up*/ ?> <fieldset> <!-- Form Name --> <h1 class="section-heading" style="text-align: center;">Login</h1> <!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" id = "email" placeholder="user@domain.com" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Password input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="********" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Button --> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Submit"></label> <div class="col-md-4"> <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> </div> </fieldset> </form> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('message'); ?> <p class="text-muted" style="text-align:center">Don't have an account yet? Click <a href="../register">here</a> to register.</p> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('auth.partials.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>', 'lock' => false))
at file_put_contents('/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php', '<?php $__env->startSection('title'); ?> Admin Login <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('form'); ?> <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action = "login"> <?php echo e($error); ?><?php /*TODO this doesn't show up now, when you do login make it show up*/ ?> <fieldset> <!-- Form Name --> <h1 class="section-heading" style="text-align: center;">Login</h1> <!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" id = "email" placeholder="user@domain.com" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Password input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="********" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Button --> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Submit"></label> <div class="col-md-4"> <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> </div> </fieldset> </form> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('message'); ?> <p class="text-muted" style="text-align:center">Don't have an account yet? Click <a href="../register">here</a> to register.</p> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('auth.partials.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>', '0') in Filesystem.php line 81
at Filesystem->put('/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php', '<?php $__env->startSection('title'); ?> Admin Login <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('form'); ?> <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action = "login"> <?php echo e($error); ?><?php /*TODO this doesn't show up now, when you do login make it show up*/ ?> <fieldset> <!-- Form Name --> <h1 class="section-heading" style="text-align: center;">Login</h1> <!-- Text input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="email" name="email" type="email" id = "email" placeholder="user@domain.com" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Password input--> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="password">Password</label> <div class="col-md-4"> <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="********" class="form-control input-md" required=""> </div> </div> <!-- Button --> <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="Submit"></label> <div class="col-md-4"> <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> </div> </fieldset> </form> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php $__env->startSection('message'); ?> <p class="text-muted" style="text-align:center">Don't have an account yet? Click <a href="../register">here</a> to register.</p> <?php $__env->stopSection(); ?> <?php echo $__env->make('auth.partials.master', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>') in BladeCompiler.php line 102
at BladeCompiler->compile('/srv/something/site/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php') in CompilerEngine.php line 51
at CompilerEngine->get('/srv/something/site/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'error' => '')) in View.php line 135
at View->getContents() in View.php line 106
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 80
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 197
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1030
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 95
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(authController), object(Route), object(Request), 'getAdminLogin') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\authController', 'getAdminLogin') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 703
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 705
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 678
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 654
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

So far, to try to fix this I've done the following:

1. Checked permissions, changed everything to `777` and to be owned by `www-data`
2. Tried recloning the empty repository with no vendor file, to no avail, same error on composer install
3. Ran `php artisan cache:clear`
4. Ran `php artisan clear-compiled`
5. Ran `php artisan dump-autoload`
6. Modified `site/config/view.php` on an `irc` suggestion, and changed  `compiled' => realpath(storage_path().'/framework/views')` to  `'compiled' => storage_path('framework/views'),` which yielded a different error: `file_put_contents(/srv/something/site/storage/framework/views/8ff8cea6e3bb10ecec87b9d62c64f9768c4c4ab1.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory` (probably because it's not supposed to be there, but who knows this information could be useful.)

All of this to no avail.  The weird part is this issue seemingly showed up out of nowhere.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems to be pretty clearly a permissions issue. I know you said you blasted a `777`, but where did you do it? I would go ahead and try a recursive 777 on the storage directory: `chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: @jpschroeder I tried that to no avail, here's an ls -l of my laravel root and the storage directory directory: https://git.io/vzxAE

Comment: Your ls -l shows that the whole directory is owned by root and the storage directory isn't writable, so I don't think you're changing permissions correctly. `cd {laravel_root}` and run `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .` `sudo chmod -R 777 storage`

Comment: @judereid I just fixed it, and it's doing the same thing as before (new ls -l): https://git.io/vzhWr .  I'm pretty sure the error has to do with the php artisan clear-compiled error working.

Comment: Setting 777 is a bad habit, consider setting the group to your webserver user and give permission to only that group to write in that folder. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/987864

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a view directories in  `laravel_root/storage/`.  In order to fix this, all I had to do was:

1. `cd {laravel_root}/storage`
2. `mkdir -pv framework/views app framework/sessions framework/cache`
3. `cd ..`
4. `chmod 664 -R storage`
5. `chown -R www-data:www-data storage`

After that, upon reloading, the issue was fixed. Thanks to `Someguy123` from `#laravel` on `freenode` for fixing this issue!

Comment: Glad you were able to get it running. It's odd that you had to create those directories manually as they are part of the original [laravel repo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage/framework). Did you use the `composer create-project` command when installing?

Comment: @jpschroeder yep, the issue was with git accidentally deleting the files.

Comment: Setting 777 is a bad habit, consider setting the group to your webserver user and give permission to only that group to write in that folder. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/987864

Comment: How about in windows?

Comment: @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol make sure you use an admin user on windows

Comment: After doing this I'm getting permission denied on Artisan commands.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.This was after creating a new project using git clone.Turns out it was because i had /storage/framework/views/ on gitignore file.I simply `mkdir storage/framework/views/` and `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage` and all was okay again.Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

If your permissions are 777 for Laravel Application folder and are still getting that error, it's because Seliux has blocked it. The application folder can be unblocked with the command below

```
su -c "chcon -R -h -t httpd_sys_script_rw_t /var/www/laravel-folder"
```

Comment: If you have SElinux (check /var/log/audit/audit.log) and you try include php-files outside of http root folder, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395845/tell-selinux-to-give-apache-execute-access-to-php-files-outside-document-root

Comment: NEVER use 777 permissions. See stackoverflow.com/a/37266353/470749

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for me was working only one solution: to add sudo:
sudo php artisan storage:link - like this

Comment: This is not an answer, it could have been a response to the original post instead of an answer. Please note next time, thanks .

Comment: Randomly running something with sudo just to check whether this solves a problem is always a bad idea